# PACKAGE_REMOVED & then PACKAGE_ADDED are fired along with PACKAGE_REPLACED Intent Action

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

All I am trying to do is update my list on each Install & Uninstall but **not** on Package Replace .So the main problem is that Install & Uninstall intents are launched on each Replace action.

So 
For this I have implemented a BroadcastReciever as below

```
<receiver android:name =".IntentReceiverTest.AppReciever">
  <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
         <data android:scheme="package"/> 
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

On each Replace I get 3 broadcasts with actions

- First with **PACKAGE_REMOVED** which fires AppReciever
- then after **PACKAGE_ADDED** which again fires AppReciever
- And then after few seconds **PACKAGE_REPLACED** which again fires AppReciever

So please suggest any better way to catch only Replace Action

Or

a way to **stop previously launched Services due to PACKAGE_REMOVED and PACKAGE_ADDED** action.

Comment: Am I missing something about your question or is the answer simply "don't filter intents you don't want"...?

Comment: @Blrfl I need  `PACKAGE_REMOVED` & `PACKAGE_ADDED` only when actually the packages are **installed/Uninstalled** but not when they are **Replaced**.Read 3rd line of my question.

Comment: Read 2nd line of your intent-filter, then read Birfl's comment, then read again 2nd line of your intent-filter.

Comment: @dziobas If I do not catch PACKAGE_REPLACED action all I get is PACKAGE_REMOVED & then PACKAGE_ADDED action each time an app is replaced.I hope you understood the question.

Comment: Make sure to construct your receiver element correctly.  I had forgotten to put the <intent-filter> tag around the action & data tags... was not getting any error, just no broadcasts

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just check `intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING, false)`:

```
if (!intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED) &&
    intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING, false))
    return;
```

Comment: `Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING` is always added to the `action.PACKAGE_REMOVED` and `action_PACKAGE_ADDED` when the app is updated. On normal installation and uninstallation this is false.

Comment: @suku in my case EXTRA_REPLACING doesn't exist in either PACKAGE_REMOVED or PACKAGE_ADDED … I wonder why