# Android package replace intent

Tags: android

In my application I am listening for following 3 intents by using broadcast receiver.

```
ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED
ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED
ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED
```

The problem is that whenever I reinstall some application First I get 
`ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` then I get `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` then I get `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`.

Is there any way to know that in reinstallation of application the `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` and `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` intents belongs to `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`. I mean these are not the intents when only application is removed and installed respectively.

Thx
Dalvin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be too late, but I was looking for something similar and came across the extra [EXTRA_REPLACING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_REPLACING) which will be present in the intent `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` if it will be immediately followed by an Add.

I figured this extra could be used to differentiate between actual replacement and only additions/removals. And sure enough, I came across [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217237/package-removed-then-package-added-are-fired-along-with-package-replaced-intent/5577746#5577746) which does the exact same thing.