# Android push using parse stops working after some time

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am using Parse to send out targeted push notifications on Android. Followed the tutorial a couple of times (sleepless nights included) and it works perfectly, however at certain unpredictable events, android users of the app stop receiving notifications. This certainly happens after a couple of hours of uploading an update on Google Play.

To reproduce it without uploading to Google Play, I narrowed it down to when I update the app's version number from the manifest and re-run without deleting and reinstalling. However, making a simple change in the manifest makes it work again. However the solution is not reliable as it will stop working again after a few hours / after uploading to production.

I am using a custom ParsePushBroadcastReceiver to play a custom sound. I am using Google Play Services 5 for location updates. And I am subscribing to the channel I am pushing to in a later activity. Any ideas of what might be causing such a problem? Code pasted below:

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx"
    android:versionCode="19"
    android:versionName="3.077" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <!-- GCM PERMISSIONS -->
    <permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <application
        android:name="com.xxx.xxx.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:logo= "@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <service android:name="com.xxx.xxx.xxxLocationService" />

         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
                    android:value="id:xxxxx" />
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.xxx.xxx.xxxBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.xxx.xxx" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(){
           Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
           ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
       }
}
```

dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile files('libs/PayPal_MPL.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.8.3.jar')
}
```

ParsePushBroadcastReceiver

```
public class xxxBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String jsonData = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);

            String title = null;
            if(json.has("title")) {
                title = json.getString("title");
            }

            String message = null;
            if(json.has("alert")) {
                message = json.getString("alert");
            }

            if(message != null) {
                generateNotification(context, title, message);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("NOTIF ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }


    private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationManager mNotifM = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if(title == null) {
            title = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        }

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(message))
                        .addAction(0, "View", contentIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setDefaults(new NotificationCompat().DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                        .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.whistle));

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mNotifM.notify(randInt(100000000, 999999999), mBuilder.build());
    }

    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

        // NOTE: Usually this should be a field rather than a method
        // variable so that it is not re-seeded every call.
        Random rand = new Random();

        // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
        // so add 1 to make it inclusive
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNum;
    }

}
```

Subscribing to the channel

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jobs);

    ...

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("driver");
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's how I'm reproducing the issue at the moment. I run in debug mode and it works, then I change the version number of the app and export a signed application for production (without running). I install that signed APK onto the device (after deleting) and notifications stop working. Seems like overriding the ParsePushBroadcastReceiver has nothing to do with it. If I delete and re-run in debug mode with the same version number it wouldn't work until I change something in the manifest like the BroadcastReceiver. This is the way I managed to reproduce it, however the notification would have stopped working anyway by the time it reaches Google Play (trying it again right now). What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried throwing the Released in Production switch to ON in the App setting on the Parse Dashboard?

Comment: Yes it's on. Could it be perhaps Google is blocking the app from GCM for some reason? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Your `onReceive` is never called as well after the version number change? Also, any logs you can share? In pure GCM implementations (meaning no Parse), response errors are sent back to your app servers if there are problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [example implementation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-register) is this comment:

```
// Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
// since the existing registration ID is not guaranteed to work with
// the new app version.
```

I'm sure that you run into this. So the solution would be to register your app after an update. I guess in your case the best option is to look on the `PACKAGE_REPLACED` event, there you should register your app again. Check also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5217237/995926) to see how it works.